# Shift key autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

My main problem is my autohotkey seems to be using my <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when I ask it to use just the hotkey I assigned.

To be quick, I am playing a game that requires to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> sometimes and with the script I put, it seems that pressing my é key is triggering my <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for 0.5 sec top.

Here is my script:

```
SendMode Input
{
~é::
~+é::
Send {3 down}{4 down}{5 down}{6 down}{3 up}{4 up}{5 up}{6 up}
return
}
```

By the way, even when I remove the line `~+é::,` it reacts as if I was pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> in the game.
I really don't understand since I am kind of new and it has been some times I am trying everything so I am asking for a bit of help here.

Thanks in advance for reading me,

lukas

Comment: What do you want your script to do?

Comment: When I press the "é" key on my keyboard, I want it to be like if I pressed 3456 / "'(-

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
~é:: ;because of the ~ the key will send itself and thus output: é3456
    SendInput, 3456
Return
```

or maybe:

```
é:: ;without the ~ the key doesn't send itself anymore and thus output: "'(-
    SendInput, "'(-
Return
```